# tableview update only when clicking tableview swift

Tags: swift, download, tableview, reload

I have a really peculiar problem. I have a JSON download and then a tableView.reloaed() statement. Now, when I run the app then the tableview does not show anything, only when I click the tableview it actually updates and shows the data correctly. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with this code: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { self.tableView.reloadData() return })